# Update element in ListView from LiveData in ViewModel on Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, android-livedata

I am making an app that is composed of a single activity.

The user can create an array of predefined size by clicking a button. And with an other button, I want the array to be sorted using various algorithms.

The algorithm and their performance time are displayed in a `ListView`. See the screenshot below as an example:
[image: example of the activity at launch]

My `listView` is created like this in `MainActivity`:

```
listView.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this)
```

and below is the adpter code:

```
class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter() {

    private val mContext: Context = context

    val names = MainActivityViewModel().allAlgorithms

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return names.size
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return names[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
        val row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_algorithm, p2, false)

        val nameTextView = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.algoName)
        nameTextView.text = names[p0].name

        val timer = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timer)
        timer.text = names[p0].time

        return row
    }
}
```

`allAlgorithms` that comes from my `ViewModel` is a `MutableList<Algorithm>`.

The Algorithm class:

```
class Algorithm(var name: String, var time: String = "0.00 sec")
```

For the moment this `MutableList<Algorithm>` is initialized using a `listOf(various algo names)`. This means that the time is kept to default value.

Now when the user clicks the start benchmark button, this function is called in my `ViewModel`:

```
private var _executionTime = MutableLiveData<Long>(timer)
val executionTime: LiveData<Long>
    get() = _executionTime

private var _index = MutableLiveData(0)
val index: LiveData<Int>
    get() = _index

fun startBench() {
    for ((i,v) in names.withIndex()) {
        _executionTime.value = measureTimeMillis {
            arr.sort() // is the arr generated by clicking the button
        }
        _index.value = i
    }
}
```

I will make different functions for each algorithms later, but for now I want my `ListView` to be updated to my `executionTime.value()` for the right algorithm.

I have tried to put an observer inside my adapter, but I cannot get a `ViewModelProvider` since I did not find a way to access a LifeCycleOwner.

I also have tried to update my `allAlgorithm` list but of course it doesn't update the UI.

**MY QUESTIONS:**

- How can I update my ListView using LiveData ?
- Is there a better way to achieve what I want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing a pretty obvious mistake that was causing my notifyDataSetChanged() not to work:

In `MyCustomAdapter` instead of passing the original version of the `MainActivityViewModel`, I was instanciating new `viewModel` every call which is not smart.

The easy fix was to pass my instance of `MainActivityViewModel` to the adapter like this:

```
    val adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this, viewModel)
    listView.adapter = adapter
```

And mofify the adapter accordingly:

```
class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context, vm: MainActivityViewModel): BaseAdapter()
```

and the changes were taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through a similar situation before. I thought like while the adapter lifecycle is tight to the activity lifecycle so I can pass the `LifecycleOwner` to the adapter and it worked perfectly

I even inserted more than 500 Item in my list for testing the performance with each list item holding a `LiveData` observer, and I didn't find any problems in that.

Maybe this is not the best solution but at least you can give it a try

Comment: Thx for your answer. Can you explain me how you passed the lifeCycleOwner please ? Also, did you use notifyDataSetChanged anywhere ?